# how to annotate heatmap with text in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am plotting a heatmap in matplotlib using:

`plt.pcolor(rand(5,5))`

how can I annotate the heatmap with the actual numbers plotted? meaning in each cell of the plotted heatmap, put the value corresponding to that cell in the 5x5 matrix passed to `pcolor`. thanks.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is no automatic feature to do such a thing, but you could loop through each point and put text in the appropriate location:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(5, 4)
heatmap = plt.pcolor(data)

for y in range(data.shape[0]):
    for x in range(data.shape[1]):
        plt.text(x + 0.5, y + 0.5, '%.4f' % data[y, x],
                 horizontalalignment='center',
                 verticalalignment='center',
                 )

plt.colorbar(heatmap)

plt.show()
```

[image: Code output]

HTH

Answer (score 9):

The seaborn heatmap does the job automatically, by setting `annot=True`.

See [this](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) for an example.