# Annotate heatmap with value from Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, text, matplotlib, pandas, heatmap

I would like to annotate a heatmap with the values that I pass from a dataframe into the function below. I have looked at matplotlib.text but have not been able to get the values from my dataframe in a desired way in my heatmap. I have pasted in my function for generating a heatmap below, after that my dataframe and the output from the heatmap call. I would like to plot each value from my dataframe in the center of each cell in the heatmap.

Function for generating a heatmap:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

def heatmap_binary(df,
            edgecolors='w',
            #cmap=mpl.cm.RdYlGn,
            log=False):    
    width = len(df.columns)/7*10
    height = len(df.index)/7*10

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))#(figsize=(width,height))

    cmap, norm = mcolors.from_levels_and_colors([0, 0.05, 1],['Teal', 'MidnightBlue'] ) # ['MidnightBlue', Teal]['Darkgreen', 'Darkred']

    heatmap = ax.pcolor(df ,
                        edgecolors=edgecolors,  # put white lines between squares in heatmap
                        cmap=cmap,
                        norm=norm)


    ax.autoscale(tight=True)  # get rid of whitespace in margins of heatmap
    ax.set_aspect('equal')  # ensure heatmap cells are square
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')  # put column labels at the top
    ax.tick_params(bottom='off', top='off', left='off', right='off')  # turn off ticks

    plt.yticks(np.arange(len(df.index)) + 0.5, df.index, size=20)
    plt.xticks(np.arange(len(df.columns)) + 0.5, df.columns, rotation=90, size= 15)

    # ugliness from http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html
    from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", "3%", pad="1%")
    plt.colorbar(heatmap, cax=cax)


plt.show()
```

Herre is an example of My dataframe :

```
dataframe :

             0-5 km / h  5-40 km / h  40-80 km / h  80-120 km / h  \
NORDIC         0.113955     0.191888      0.017485      -0.277528   
MIDDLE  EU     0.117903     0.197084     -0.001447      -0.332677   
KOREA          0.314008     0.236503     -0.067174      -0.396518   
CHINA          0.314008     0.236503     -0.067174      -0.396518   

             120-160 km / h  160-190 km / h  190 km / h  
NORDIC            -0.054365        0.006107    0.002458  
MIDDLE  EU         0.002441        0.012097    0.004599  
KOREA             -0.087191        0.000331    0.000040  
CHINA             -0.087191        0.000331    0.000040
```

Generating the heatmap:

```
heatmap_binary(dataframe)
```

[image]

Any ideas?

---

Update to clarify my problem

I tried the proposed solution from question which has the result I'm looking for:
[how to annotate heatmap with text in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917547/how-to-annotate-heatmap-with-text-in-matplotlib)
However, I still have a problem using the matplotlib.text function for positioning the values in the heatmap:
Here is my cod for trying this solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


data = dataframe.values
heatmap_binary(dataframe)

for y in range(data.shape[0]):
    for x in range(data.shape[1]):
        plt.text(data[y,x] +0.05 , data[y,x] + 0.05, '%.4f' % data[y, x], #data[y,x] +0.05 , data[y,x] + 0.05
                 horizontalalignment='center',
                 verticalalignment='center',
                 color='w')

#plt.colorbar(heatmap)

plt.show()
```

added plot: (different coloring but same problem)
[image]

Comment: What goes wrong when you try this?  Can you post an image?

Comment: Added a picture, different coloring but same problem though. The text call places the values in the right hand corner....

Comment: Can you post a copy of your code all at once, not in two distinct chunks?  I think the problem is that you're running your `for` loop *after* you've added the `colorbar`.  Try running the `text` `for` loop **immediately after** the call to `pcolor`.

Comment: I tried to put the for loop iside the heatmap_binary function after the pcolor...did not work though...I got the same result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The values you were using for your coordinates in your `for` loop were screwed up.  Also you were using `plt.colorbar` instead of something cleaner like `fig.colorbar`.  Try this (it gets the job done, with no effort made to otherwise cleanup the code):

```
def heatmap_binary(df,
            edgecolors='w',
            #cmap=mpl.cm.RdYlGn,
            log=False):    
    width = len(df.columns)/7*10
    height = len(df.index)/7*10

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))#(figsize=(width,height))

    cmap, norm = mcolors.from_levels_and_colors([0, 0.05, 1],['Teal', 'MidnightBlue'] ) # ['MidnightBlue', Teal]['Darkgreen', 'Darkred']

    heatmap = ax.pcolor(df ,
                        edgecolors=edgecolors,  # put white lines between squares in heatmap
                        cmap=cmap,
                        norm=norm)
    data = df.values
    for y in range(data.shape[0]):
        for x in range(data.shape[1]):
            plt.text(x + 0.5 , y + 0.5, '%.4f' % data[y, x], #data[y,x] +0.05 , data[y,x] + 0.05
                 horizontalalignment='center',
                 verticalalignment='center',
                 color='w')


    ax.autoscale(tight=True)  # get rid of whitespace in margins of heatmap
    ax.set_aspect('equal')  # ensure heatmap cells are square
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')  # put column labels at the top
    ax.tick_params(bottom='off', top='off', left='off', right='off')  # turn off ticks

    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(df.index)) + 0.5)
    ax.set_yticklabels(df.index, size=20)
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(df.columns)) + 0.5)
    ax.set_xticklabels(df.columns, rotation=90, size= 15)

    # ugliness from http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html
    from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", "3%", pad="1%")
    fig.colorbar(heatmap, cax=cax)
```

Then

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0, 0.75], size=(4,5)), columns=list('ABCDE'), index=list('WXYZ'))
heatmap_binary(df1)
```

gives:

[image: The Answer]

Comment: Happy to help.  I wonder if this is worth proposing as an enhancement to Pandas.  There are all sorts of things I wish I could do with Pandas DataFrames in this spirit.  Color only certain columns.  Normalize before coloring.  Etc.  The open question for me is "what's the right general approach"?  I.e. Is it something based on `pcolor` or is it something that should involve the DataFrame HTML representation?  What do you guys think?

Comment: Yes, such enhancement in diagraming would be helpful. In the spirit of simplifying data processing, they are very much welcomed. Especially, the labeling of values on heatmap is very much needed. So common, it would save some effort with some straightforward API.

Answer (score 9):

This functionality is provided by the [seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/heatmap_annotation.html) package. It can produce maps like

[image: Example annotated heatmap]

An example usage of [seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/heatmap_annotation.html) is

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

# Load the example flights dataset and conver to long-form
flights_long = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights_long.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")

# Draw a heatmap with the numeric values in each cell
sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, fmt="d", linewidths=.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're using `plt.text` after you've added another axes.

The state machine will plot on the *current* axes, and after you've added a new one with `divider.append_axes`, the colorbar's axes is the current one.  (Just calling `plt.colorbar` will not cause this, as it sets the current axes back to the original one afterwards if it creates the axes itself. If a specific axes object is passed in using the `cax` kwarg, it doesn't reset the "current" axes, as that's not what you'd normally want.)

Things like this are the main reason that you'll see so many people advising that you use the OO interface to matplotlib instead of the state machine interface.  That way you know which axes object that you're plotting on.

For example, in your case, you could have `heatmap_binary` return the `ax` object that it creates, and the plot using `ax.text` instead of `plt.text` (and similar for the other plotting methods).

Comment: Thank you. So, do you have any suggestions of how to return an axis object from my function. I'm afraid I'm not so skilled in the python language..

Answer (score 1):

You also can use **plotly.figure_factory** to create heatmap **from DataFrame**, but you have **convert** it **into list**.

```
    import plotly.figure_factory as ff

    z = [your_dataframe].values.tolist()
    x = [your_dataframe].columns.tolist()
    y = [your_dataframe].index.tolist()

    fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z, x=x, y=y, annotation_text=z, colorscale='viridis')

    # for add annotation into Heatmap
    for i in range(len(fig.layout.annotations)):
        fig.layout.annotations[i].font.size = 12

    # show your Heatmap
    fig.show()
```