# How to plot percentage of points in each "cell" of pyplot.hist2d?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I want each "cell" of the histogram to have a number representing the percentage of total points in that "cell" instead of colors. Is there any way other than programmatically generating the matrix?
[2D histogram of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnyDH.png)

On [M.T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5422525/m-thttp://) 's suggestion, I think seaborn.heatmap() asks for a 2D data array. But I have two 1D arrays (say height and weight and each data point will be a person with (height, weight) value. Code is here:) and the array values have no particular order. Sample code here:

```
plt.hist2d(height, weight, (20, 50), range=np.array([(0, 200), (0, 500)]), cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Perhaps look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917547/how-to-annotate-heatmap-with-text-in-matplotlib) to get some ideas. In particular [seaborn's heatmap](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) with `annot=True`

Comment: You mean something like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnp3E.png ?

Comment: Yes, something like that. But with the bin boundaries being the cell boundaries so that any line of correlation can be drawn on the graph itself.

Comment: Could you add example arrays for `height` and `weight`?

Comment: height = [102, 99, 153, 98, 142, 198, 99], 
weight = [201, 192, 295, 181, 315, 311, 181].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use text and loop through the output to the normed `hist2d`, as follows,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

height = [102, 99, 153, 98, 142, 198, 99]
weight = [201, 192, 295, 181, 315, 311, 181]

counts, xedges, yedges, Image = plt.hist2d(height, weight, (20, 50), 
                                           range=np.array([(0, 200), (0, 500)]), 
                                           cmap=plt.cm.Paired, normed=True)

dx = xedges[2]-xedges[1]
dy = yedges[2]-yedges[1]
for i in range(xedges.size-1):
    for j in range(yedges.size-1):
        xb = xedges[i] + 0.25*dx
        yb = yedges[j] + 0.25*dy 
        plt.text(xb, yb, str(np.round(100.*counts[i,j],2)), fontsize=6 )

plt.show()
```

which gives,
[image]

Comment: modified the code a bit : removed normed=True, kept a total count and did :

str(np.round(100.*counts[i,j]/total,2)) instead.

Comment: Yeah, that may be better, I think `normed` is by histogram area not simply by count.