# How to Annotate sublots of heatmaps in matplotlip

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting a heatmap in matplotlib using custom defined function and would like to add annotation for 
each box in grid. basically each grid should show 3,4's annotated. I think the solution is not trivial so I have done some research before asking here

By following the instructions from these posts
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10956
[how to annotate heatmap with text in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917547/how-to-annotate-heatmap-with-text-in-matplotlib/11918066)
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html

I tried to solve the problem but it seems that I'm missing something.

Then I added a for loop under `facet` function below but it does not output desired plot and throwing a KeyError: (0,0)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def expandgrid(*itrs):
   product = list(itertools.product(*itrs))
   return {'Var{}'.format(i+1):[x[i] for x in product] for i in range(len(itrs))}

methods=["m" + str(i) for i in range(1,3)]
labels=["l" + str(i) for i in range(1,4)]

times = range(0,100,25)
data = pd.DataFrame(expandgrid(methods,labels, times, times))
data.columns = ['method','labels','dtsi','rtsi']
#data['nw_score'] = np.random.sample(data.shape[0])
data['nw_score'] = np.random.choice([3,4],data.shape[0])

data.head()

method labels  dtsi  rtsi  nw_score
0     m1     l1     0     0         4
1     m1     l1     0    25         4
2     m1     l1     0    50         4
3     m1     l1     0    75         3
4     m1     l1    25     0         3

cmap=ListedColormap(['red', 'blue'])

def facet(data, ax):
    data = data.pivot(index="dtsi", columns='rtsi', values='nw_score')
    ax.imshow(data, cmap=cmap,extent=[0,100,0,100])
    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        for j in range(data.shape[1]):
            ax.text(j, i, "{:.2f}".format(data[i,j]), ha="center", va="center")



def myfacetgrid(data, row, col, figure=None):
    rows = np.unique(data[row].values)  
    cols = np.unique(data[col].values)

    fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 2, 
                            figsize=(2*len(cols)+1, 2*len(rows)+1))

    for i, r in enumerate(rows):
        row_data = data[data[row] == r]
        for j, c in enumerate(cols):
            this_data = row_data[row_data[col] == c]
            facet(this_data, axs[i,j])
    return fig, axs

with sns.plotting_context(font_scale=5.5):
    fig, axs = myfacetgrid(data, row="labels", col="method")


    for ax,method in zip(axs[0,:],data.method.unique()):
        ax.set_title(method, fontweight='bold', fontsize=12)
    for ax,label in zip(axs[:,0],data.labels.unique()):
        ax.set_ylabel(label, fontweight='bold', fontsize=12, rotation=0, ha='right', va='center')
        #fig.suptitle(lt, fontweight='bold', fontsize=12)
    fig.tight_layout()
    fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.8) # make some room for the title
```

[image]

After adding for loop to `facet` function it seems that everything fall aparts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following changes to the `facet` function:

- Converting the result of `data.pivot` to an `np.array` such that it is addressable as `data[i,j]`.
- Leaving out `extent=[0,100,0,100]` out of `ax.imshow`, because that extent changes the coordinate system and prevents the use of `i` and `j` to position the text.

That seems to work.

```py
def facet(data, ax):
    data = np.array(data.pivot(index="dtsi", columns='rtsi', values='nw_score'))
    ax.imshow(data, cmap=cmap)
    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        for j in range(data.shape[1]):
            ax.text(j, i, "{:.2f}".format(data[i,j]), ha="center", va="center")
```

Comment: Its very helpful solution. Indeed, I was trying to output this part
`def facet(data):
    data = np.array(data.pivot(index="dtsi", columns='rtsi', values='nw_score'))`

and run `facet(data)` but getting this error `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`  How can look into facet function output ?