# Show the correlation in my correlation plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, correlation

I created the following function to create a correlation matrix:

```
def correlation_matrix(df):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 13))
    plt.matshow(df.corr(), fignum=f.number, cmap='RdYlBu')
    plt.xticks(range(df.select_dtypes(['number']).shape[1]), df.select_dtypes(['number']).columns, fontsize=13, rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(range(df.select_dtypes(['number']).shape[1]), df.select_dtypes(['number']).columns, fontsize=13)
    cb = plt.colorbar()
    cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=14)
    plt.title('Correlation Matrix', fontsize=18);

correlation_matrix(df)
```

The output looks as followed: [image: Correlation_Matrix]

How can I add the correlation values within each cell? For example show a value of 0.58 in a call if that's the corresponing correlation? Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to annotate heatmap with text in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917547/how-to-annotate-heatmap-with-text-in-matplotlib)

Comment: You can also use seaborn's [`sns.heatmap(data=df.corr(), annot=True)`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) to do the heavy lifting. See also [this tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0U9cs2V-Mqc) which explains lots of tips and tricks.